# Deleting a variation label

Tags: 2010, variations

How do I delete a variation label for which hierarchies have already been created?

I have searched through the settings pages at the site collection level but there is no option there. I have also looked in central admin but cannot find anywhere to remove a variation label.

Searching Google I similarly found nothing. I did find in Stefan Gossner's complete guide to variations part 10 (http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/25/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-10-restructuring-the-hierarchy.aspx) a reference to deleting variation labels (see bottom of page). This implies that it is possible but doesn't explain how. It does indicate that the process is long running, naturally, and suggests that the request timeout is increased and that app pool recycling is disabled whilst the variation is deleted, but provides no info on how to start the process.

He does provide a config sample that shows how to increase the request timeout that specifically targets the page /_layouts/VariationLabels.aspx - however this page has no option to delete a variation.

Does anyone know how to do this? Can I just delete the SPWeb for the variation label or will this cause issues and have no effect on the variation labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Variation Labels page click in the whitespace next to the label and select Delete in the ECB menu:

[image]

Comment: Well thank you for a painful lesson in expecting the obvious. Curiously I don't see a roll over state for the menu (as I do on list pages for example) until clicking in the empty white space beside the label (I had of course tried clicking the label before posting here!). Two lessons in fact; firstly a valuable reminder of the importance of UXD with an excellent example of 'what not to do' and secondly a valuable reminder to click more before asking questions! Thank you.